# How to check duplicate rows in dataset?

Tags: c#, dataset

[image]

I have a dataset which has duplicate rows i want my error message to execute when duplicate rows are present.

Below is my code please help

```
DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();

dsXml.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));
Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow drow in dsXml.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (hTable.Contains(drow))
    {
        duplicateList.Add(drow);
    }
    else
    {
        script.Append("alert('Error - There are some Duplicate entries.'); ");
        ErrorOcc = true;
        if (ErrorOcc)
        {
            this.ScriptOutput = script + " ValidateBeforeSaving = false;";
            this.StayContent = "yes";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not working, because `DataRow` instances will be compared by references instead of comparing their fields. You can use custom comparer:

```
public class CustomDataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        if (x.ItemArray.Length != y.ItemArray.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.ItemArray.Length; i++)                            
            if (!x[i].Equals(y[i]))
                return false;            

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (object field in obj.ItemArray)
            hash = hash * 19 + field.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

or use existing [`DataRowComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which compares `DataRow` objects for equivalence by using value-based comparison:

```
HashSet<DataRow> set = new HashSet<DataRow>(DataRowComparer.Default);
// or: new HashSet<DataRow>(new CustomDataRowComparer());

foreach (DataRow row in dsXml.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!set.Add(row))
        // duplicate row
}
```

You can also check if duplicated rows exist with Linq to DataSet query:

```
var duplicatedRowsExist = dsXml.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                               .GroupBy(r => r, DataRowComparer.Default)
                               .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the content of the rows, not the rows themselves. Something like this should do it:

```
var hasDupes = dsXml.Tables[0].Rows
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new 
     { 
           row.Field<string>("Title"), 
           row.Field<string>("Address"), 
           row.Field<string>("State"), 
           row.Field<string>("City"), 
           row.Field<int>("Status"), 
           row.Field<int>("CreatedBy"), 
           row.Field<int>("UpdatedBy") 
     })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Any();

if(hasDupes)
  //Show error message
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to alter you logic a little. You don't add the row to the hTable, so there are never duplicates. And I guess you have to show the message in the end, else the list will not be complete yet.

As stated by others, you do need Sergeys answer to get the comparison to work. If you have that covered, this code will solve the other logic problems.

```
foreach (DataRow drow in dsXml.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!hTable.Contains(drow))
    {
        hTable.Contains(drow);
        hTable.Add(drow);
    }
    else
    {
        duplicateList.Add(drow);
    }
}

script.Append("alert('Error - There are some Duplicate entries.'); ");
ErrorOcc = true;
if (ErrorOcc)
{
    this.ScriptOutput = script + " ValidateBeforeSaving = false;";
    this.StayContent = "yes";
    return;
}
```

Comment: This will use the default `DataRow` equality comparison

Comment: @Simon: that is true, I saw the excellent answer of Sergey. Nonetheless, the code is bad even with that implemented. I suggest OP to merge the two answers together in one.

Comment: @Simon: changed the answer to include reference to Sergeys answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define your comparison between rows. It appears when you create your `hTable` there is nothing in it, so the `hTable.Contains` call is always going to return false.

As a side note, you can't just compare a `DataRow` with another `DataRow`, it will use the default equality comparison (implemented using IEqualityComparer) and effectively boils down to a reference equality check, which none of the rows will be equal to each other.

Somewhere, you can either implement your own `IEqualityCompariosn`, or simply write a custom method to check the values of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of my above Question

You can Check duplicate rows in dataset.. it is working fine try it.

```
                DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();
                dsXml.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));

                List<string> duplicateList = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataRow drow in dsXml.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    string strr = "";

                    for (int j = 0; j < dsXml.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++ )
                    {
                        strr += drow[j];
                    }

                    if (!duplicateList.Contains(strr))
                    {
                        duplicateList.Add(strr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        script.Append("alert('Error - There are some Duplicate entries.'); ");
                        ErrorOcc = true;
                        if (ErrorOcc)
                        {
                            this.ScriptOutput = script + " ValidateBeforeSaving = false;";
                            this.StayContent = "yes";
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```